# Website loads incorrectly on mobile browsers. "width=device-width" doesn't work and parts of the header/footer remain grey

Tags: html, mobile, meta-tags, head

My title is pretty self explanatory, my website loads incorrectly on mobile devices (I've only tried it on iPhone and iPad). First of all "width=device-width" doesn't work, but "width=device-320" does work. I would like to get "width=device-width" to work.

Also, regardless of how the page loads, or if i enter "width=device-width" or "width=device-320" in the head tag, parts of my header and footer disappear. Why does this keep happening?

Thanks!

More Info:

Site URL: http://www.TeenageLifestyle.com

Header error: http://tinypic.com/r/2qlseu0/5

Answer (score 0):

Try `width=100%`, it's what I always use.